# Is it OK to redirect to a new address instead of showing 404 Error page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo, google-search-console

Here is my question, Recently I moved my site from blog.example.com to www.example.com.

Then I added 301 permanent redirection using this code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Everything was OK, and when I go to my site by typing blog.example.com it automatically redirected to www.example.com.

But, I found that when I click a Google search result of my old site doesn't redirect to the new site.

Guess Google result URL is

blog.example.com/how-to-create-simple-but-fully-styled-navigation

Though it doesn't redirect to

www.example.com/how-to-create-simple-but-fully-styled-navigation

It only goes to the old URL which is

blog.example.com/how-to-create-simple-but-fully-styled-navigation

which shows my hosting provider's 404 Error page.

So, then what I did was creating a custom 404 error page and added a php code to get the Google's search result URL and replace the word 'blog' with 'www' then redirecting to

www.example.com/how-to-create-simple-but-fully-styled-navigation

So, now everything's working perfectly and no any error pages.

But I want to know if what I've done is OK with SEO logics. I've heard that 301 permanent redirection tells the Search engines that the site has moved. And where the new site is.

I want to know if there's no damage to 301 redirection after I've created custom 404 page and added a tricky redirection...

Thanks... Hope you understand. :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Cross-posted on WordPress SE.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/161201)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pages are gone for good, put a 410 page.

But if they still exist, only under different domain, use 301. Google will slowly replace those pages in the index and in a month or so it will be fine.

Avoid using too many redirects - Google may treat this as malicious action.

Comment: If the pages are gone for good, put a `410` page not a `404`.

Comment: thank you, I was in a hurry :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does "pages are gone for good" means ? Intentionally removing a page ?

Comment: What I meant was deleting a page with no intentions of making it active ever again.

Comment: OK thank you sir, by the way do you think my redirection will be seen as a malicious action by google ? I mean in a scenario like this, what would you do if you were me... :-) Thanks...

Comment: I did not get whether or not you are using two redirects - one to 404 and then another one to the new domain, or just one - to the new domain? If it is the latter, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Yes, to be honest, it contains two redirects. One is 404 redirect on .htaccess and the other redirect on 404 error page. So, I think I should remove the second redirect and leave just 404 or 410 page.